# Redirect page to inside directory using htaccess, keeps looping

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect http://sub.domain.com/summit/ to http://sub.domain.com/summit/home/. After googling i found few rules but none of them working it keeps looping and adds /summit/home multiple times, Below is why i tried last

```
RewriteRule summit/(.*)$ /summit/home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I want to redirect http://sub.domain.com/summit/ to http://sub.domain.com/summit/home/. After googling i found few rules but none of them working it keeps looping and adds /summit/home multiple times, Below is why i tried last

```
RewriteRule summit/(.*)$ /summit/home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Below is the complete .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([1-9]+)(.*)$ ?id=$1&$2 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^research/([1-9]+)(.*)$ ?id=$1&$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/summit/home [NC]
RewriteRule ^summit/(.*)$ /summit/home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: You need to use a different browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: ohh, let me give it a try

Comment: Used chrome in congnito mode as well as cleared cache and history, It stopped adding /home/home/home but now it says "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: I have tested this rule many times and there is no redirection loop in this rule. If you have other rules or other .htaccess in your system then that might be contributing. If yes can you paste your current rules in your question.

Comment: Yes there are few other rules as well, answer updated

Comment: And there is no CMS/PHP framework here right? (eg Joomla, WP etc)

Comment: Yes we are using modx cms

Comment: Ok try inserting my suggested rule just after `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: I used the rule as it is,and noticed its adding home twice, so i modified it a little bit, now it adds home only once but it says "This webpage has a redirect loop" modified rule : RewriteRule ^summit/((?!home/).*)$ /summit/home/ [R=301,NC,L]